# Can't access raspberrypi server from domain

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, raspberry-pi, cloudflare

So long story short, my webserver suddenly stopped working last saturday from nowhere when I was developing an app that was dependent on my server. Since then, I am unable to reach to the server by using the domain codenoury.se. I can connect through IP-adress (public and local) and firewall settings on both my raspberrypi and router do allow access trough port 80 (http) and 443 (https).

Using telnet also proves that port 80 and port 443 does work for the given ip-adress.
I have the correct DNS settings as well, and the same that I had before so I am not sure where to even begin to solve this issue...

I am using Nginx, together with PM2 for NodeJS applications. The Raspberrypi does have internet connection since I am also running webscraping applications from the device which requires internet connection.

I am using cloudflare for DNS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain names don't actually carry any traffic themselves (they're not relays or tunnels) – all they do is give the HTTP clients an IP address to connect to. So the **first thing to check** is whether the domain name in fact resolves to the correct IP address, using DNS query tools such as `host`, `dig`, or `nslookup`:

```
$ host codenoury.se
Host codenoury.se not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

It doesn't resolve to anything. When the actual result is different from the expected, it may be useful to verify whether the base domain is still *delegated* to the correct nameservers (Cloudflare's in your case), by checking the parent NS records – the `dnstracer` tool is convenient for that:

```
$ dnstracer -s . codenoury.se
Tracing to codenoury.se[a] via A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET, maximum of 3 retries
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET [.] (2001:0503:ba3e:0000:0000:0000:0002:0030) 
 |\___ z.ns.se [se] (2620:010a:80ab:0000:0000:0000:0000:0150) 
 |\___ z.ns.se [se] (185.159.198.150) 
 |\___ y.ns.se ...
```

(This could be done manually using `dig se. NS` to find the parent .se nameservers, followed by `dig codenoury.se NS @z.ns.se` to query the delegation records.)

That looks like it's not delegated *at all,* which is a change that can only be done by your registrar, so check the domain's registration status via WHOIS (using the `whois` tool) – which says that your domain's registration expired a week ago:

```
$ whois codenoury.se
state:            deactivated
[...]
modified:         2022-10-01
expires:          2022-09-21
[...]
status:           pendingDelete
status:           serverHold
```

Comment: Hi, that is very weird because I expected it to expire in mid october... I will check this and get back once I have that confirmed. Thank you very much for your help